# Duplicate identifier from typescript.d.ts inclusion for sub node_modules dependencies

Tags: typescript

Here is the relevant traceResolution output:

```
https://gist.github.com/pksorensen/02aadba30dc30490c5bdc3100a4ca9ad
```

Here is my tsconfig

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "module": "amd",
    "target": "es5",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "artifacts/src/",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "artifacts/typings/",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "Ascend/*": [ "node_modules/ascend-portal/artifacts/typings/Ascend/*" ],
      "3party/*": [ "node_modules/ascend-portal/artifacts/typings/3party/*" ],
      "FxsPortal/*": [ "node_modules/ascend-portal/artifacts/typings/FxsPortal/*" ],
      "ammo-portal/*": [ "node_modules/ascend-portal/artifacts/typings/ammo-portal/*" ],
      "AscendUtils/*": [ "node_modules/ascend-utils/artifacts/typings/*" ],
      "si-portal-framework": [ "node_modules/si-portal-framework/dist/typings/si-portal-framework.d.ts" ],
      "AscendOpenLayers/*": [ "node_modules/ascend-openlayers/artifacts/typings/*" ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [ "node_modules" ]
}
```

I can't figure out from the trace output why it would end up including the openlayers index.d.ts twice from two locations, one the main dependency and the other from one of the dependencies dependency.

Comment: can you add package.json?

Comment: I found out that the issue was due to versions of dependencies not matching project dependencies versionings. I will add a more detailing answer when off work.